# Function arrow notation in multivariable functions

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, notation, multivalued-functions

How can I implement the function arrow notation in a multivariable function?

I know that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ means that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and the range is $\mathbb{Z}$ for example a function $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$, but what in a multivariable function, for example:

$$f(z,x)=w$$
$$z,w\in\mathbb{C},x\in\mathbb{R}$$

How would this be expressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be expressed as $$f: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$$ where $(z,x) \in \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}$. This means the function maps an ordered pair $(z,x)$, where the first entry is a complex number and the second entry is a real number, to a complex number $w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: this could also be written as: $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$? $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not an ordered pair, so is a pair of 3?

Comment: No, because the domain of $f$ is the Cartesian product of the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$; whereas the codomain is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: And what about a three real variable function? $f(x,y,z)=w$ where $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb{R}$. Maybe $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Agente156 -  Yes. If we have a three variable function that outputs a single number it would be $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}  \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or, more concisely, $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$.